# Visual studio 2013 login issue showing blank page

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-shell

I am using visual studio 2013 professional. I am using azure services too, So for that I have login in VS with my credentials.

After some time suddenly, it showing me anonymous user, So when I try to login in VS. first it show me message "thank you for your patience." but after 10 seconds, it shows blank dialog.

[image]

[image]

I read on other article that, I need to turn on javascript in IE. and I have done it too. Still no luck.

How can I login into it ? I am not able to publish anything on azure account.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself, for those who may get same error, The solution is,

Repair your visual studio and restart your system.

Comment: is there any other alternative ?
I am getting same issue again.

Comment: Same for me, I can't sign fully. After I enter my password, it is blank, and I can't do anything.

Comment: Try with given above mentioned solution... Repair it and restart your system.

Comment: Well, it seems that there is another sign in button on the right side, which worked.